# How to render xml in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having trouble rendering xml in a Rails app. I'm following the instructions from [here](http://danengle.us/2009/05/generating-custom-xml-for-your-rails-app/) and here's my controller:

```
...
respond_to do |format|
  format.xml { render :xml => @cases }
end
```

In my view:

```
xml.instruct!
xml.cases do
  @cases.each do |c|
    xml.case do
      xml.title c.case_number
    end
  end
end
```

Yet in my response all I'm getting is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<nil-classes type="array"/>
```

I've never worked with xml in Rails before, so I'm bit confused. My controllers structure is like this:

```
app/controllers
app/controllers/shared
app/controllers/api
```

The controllers in `app/controllers/shared` is where I keep most of my logic, so in my `app/controllers/api` I reference the shared controllers like so:

```
class Api::CampaignsController < Shared::CampaignsController
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
  before_action :authenticate
end
```

Currently, my xml template is located here: `views/campaigns/method_in_my_controller.xml.builder` but I've had similar results (no data in the xml) when I had a view file here `views/shared/campaigns/method_in_my_controller.xml.builder`

Wha am i missing?

Comment: Are you sure that `@cases` is populated before you pass it for rendering?

Comment: Yes, it is... I've run the code on console and I can clearly see the contents in `@cases`

Comment: I thought it worth checking as it's always worth trying the simple things first.

Comment: @ReggieB It makes perfect sense :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Remove

```
respond_to do |format| 
    format.xml { render :xml => @cases } 
end
```

And write

```
render :xml => @cases
```

You don't need view xml.builder. Remove it. 
Try to call `@cases.to_xml` in console. I know that [to_xml](http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/to_xml) works with hashes.

Comment: But if I remove the view, I get a `Template is missing error`. `@cases.to_xml` seems to work fine. I just don't get it in the view...

Comment: what if remove `respond_to do |format|  
  format.xml { render :xml => @cases }  
end`  And write  `render :xml => @cases`

Comment: Actually it did work. There was a mistake in my code which throwing me off. Thanks!